# Parsing an entire wordpress blog in Ruby or Python

Tags: python, ruby, wordpress, rss

I need to build an RSS feed containing every single post from a wordpress blog. I can't simply export the contents, because the wordpress installation on which the blog is hosted doesn't allow it. The RSS feed on the blog contains only the last 20 items, which is less than ideal.

Thus, I thought about writing a simple script in either Python or Ruby. I have no idea where to start, though. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `Nokogiri`. It makes parsing web pages a piece of cake.
http://hunterpowers.com/data-scraping-and-more-with-ruby-nokogiri-sinatra-and-heroku/
http://nokogiri.org/

Comment: Mind sharing the blog in question? Ihave code that does this kind thing for other Wordpress blogs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build some sort of web scraper.

For python check out [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) alongside a HTML parsing library like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)